# How to map board column to customized state in Azure Devops Server

Tags: azure-devops-server, azure-devops-server-2020

We are using Azure Devops Server and I have added a custom state called *Tested* to User Stories and bugs using the Witadmin tool. I have also added transitions to all other possible states. As you can see belo, my customized state is displayed perfectly in both the Bug form and the User story form.

[image]

But as you can see below, there is no way for me to map a Kanban board column to my customized state:

[image]

Is there somehting I have  missed or is it not possible to map a board column to customized states?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to export ProcessConfiguration definition with command `witadmin exportprocessconfig` and update the `RequirementBacklog` section for the WIT you modified. Specifically, make sure that the `Tested` state you want to have show up on the Kanban board to `type="InProgress"`:

```
<State type="InProgress" value="Tested" />
```

Then use `witadmin importprocessconfig` command to import the ProcessConfiguration definition.